# How to create a scope based on user.photos.count

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope

I have a User model and a Photo model. If I go into Heroku Console, I can search the database, for example:

```
u = User.find(2)
u.photos.count 
=> 25
```

I want to create a scope in my `User` model so that I can sort the users based on their photos.count number and then paginate the users.

```
Class User 

scope :photocount  ??????

UsersController 

def index
  @users = User.photocount.paginate(page: params[:page])
end
```

Comment: Do you mean sort users by photo count (and then paginate)?

Comment: Yes, this is what I mean, I will update the OP. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is `counter_cache`. Add a column `photos_count` to user model and in Photo model:

```
belongs_to :user, counter_cache:true
```

Then you can `User.order(:photos_count).page(params[:page])`
See more about counter cache [in rails guides here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-belongs-to-counter-cache)

Scope will look like:

```
scope :by_photos_count, ->{ order(:photos_count) }
```

Without counter cache it is still possible, but will be very inefficient:

```
User.joins('join (select user_id, count(*) as sort from photos group by user_id) as sort ON users.id=sort.user_id').order('sort.sort').page(params[:page])
```